# NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException even though jar is in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I'm really sorry for asking this (because I know there are a lot of similar questions out there) but none of them actually helped me. Basically I have multiple maven projects, lets call them ***top_module***, ***middle_module***, ***bottom_module***.

Hierarchy is as follows:

-top_module

|-----middle_module

|----------bottom_module

There's instance of one ***middle_module***'s Class in ***top_module***, and multiple instances of ***bottom_module***'s classes in ***middle_module***. Everything looks fine on compile time, but when I try to run the code, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/my/company/service/MyService
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:972)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:945)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5218)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.company.service.MyService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    ... 38 more
```

where `MyService` is in ***middle_module*** and is called from ***top_module***

When I check ***top_module***'s classpath, there are both ***middle_module*** and ***bottom_module*** as maven dependencies. If I export ***top_module*** war there are ***middle_module*** and ***bottom_module*** jars in lib folder.

Here are the pom.xml files:

top pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
<artifactId>top_module</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>middle_module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

middle pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
<artifactId>middle_module</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven-compiler.version>3.2</maven-compiler.version>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>bottom_module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

bottom pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
<artifactId>bottom_module</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven-compiler.version>3.2</maven-compiler.version>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I'm probably doing something wrong with the maven project structure but I don't know what. Any pointers to right direction are welcome.

Thank you and kind regards.

**UPDATE:** Problem wasn't the source code... It was specific to my machine. After clearing project settings, rebuilding the classpath and IDE specific settings all is good and dandy. Sorry for false alert, and big thanks to all who tried to help.

Kind regards.

Comment: How do you run the code? IMHO it's more related to running the code than to Maven (compiling).

Comment: @Thomas Both, Spring Pivotal Server, and Apache Tomcat yield the same result (mentioned above)

Comment: You would need to add the bottom module dependency too in the top module. Just like the apache-commons dependencies with spring modules, but you have to add the apache-commons also in your pom.

Comment: @JamesJithin Unfortunately, I've already tried that and it doesn't work. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: In your web project, go to Java Build Path > Libraries, expand Maven Dependencies and see if you have both the jars there. If that looks fine, depends on the way you generate the build, maven or eclipse export, open and check the dependent jars are there in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: They're there... Only thing unusual is that in Build Path configuration bottom_module and middle_module are displayed as folder structure and not as a jar archive. But after generating the build, corresponding jars are created and located in WEB-INF/lib folder.